# returns no result on xml feed

Tags: php, xml

I am very new to Php with xml. I have a xml file and i am uploading feeds, but it is not showing any result
here is my code

```
function getFeed($feed_url, $uid) {
$cnt = 0;
set_time_limit(0);
$content = url_get_contents(urldecode($feed_url));
$validXML = simplexml_load_string($content);
 if($validXML===FALSE) {
         echo "false";
    return false;
 } 
 else {
    $x = new SimpleXMLElement($content);

    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
        $category = $entry->category;
        $title = $entry->title;
        $link = $entry->link;
        $pubdate = $entry->pubDate;
        $desc = $entry->description;
        $query = "INSERT INTO `tbl_feed` ( `id` , `uid`, `category` , `title`, `link`, `pubdate`, `description` ) 
                                VALUES ('', '$uid', '$category', '$title' , '$link', '$pubdate', '".mb_convert_encoding($desc,"iso-8859-1","auto")."')";
        echo "<br />";
                    echo $cnt = $cnt+1 ."<br />";

//$dbFun->insertInto($query);
        print($query . "<br><br>");
        //  mysql_query("set CHARACTER SET UTF-8");
        //mysql_query($query); 
    }//foreach ends 
            exit();
}
}
```

Comment: It is likely that the elements you try to access do not exist. Check with `count($x->channel->item)` how many there are. Also your code is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: The count function does not display, warp it into a var_dump: `var_dump($x->channel->item, count($x->channel->item));` - should tell you more. Please see http://php.net/var_dump it is a handy function for quick trouble-shooting in PHP.

Comment: @hakre should i share that link from where i got that xml file?

Comment: Well that is always a good idea because next to your code, that would allow to reproduce what you describe.

Comment: i am facing this problem in case of only 1 xml file. ele is running fine

Comment: Yes I guess so but also your problem is not clear. You need to find out where your script fails. Just add the URL so it's clear with which feed it get's broken.

Comment: hmmm my script is loading the xml but in case of 1 url, it adds nothing. am i clear now?

Comment: Yes, clear like a sea in the mountains. Just add the URL of that feed for which your script does not work ;)

Comment: oh it was my bad. i am uploading the xml with the different format :(